# Order by last digit in a number column in oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle11g, digit, sql-order-by

I Have a number column in my table where i have to order the records basing on the last digit of that column value.

For ex, i want all the records which ends with '2' and created by 'John' first and then remaining like below
     ## Number ##     ## CreatedBy ##

```
 3234445452         John    

 3432454542         John

 3432454572         Alex

 1234567890         John

 3432432441         John
```

Thanks for your Help...

Comment: Wouldn't ordering by the last digit be `0, 1, 2, 2`?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. its just retrieving the records which ends with a particular digit first and then remaining later (at the end, all the records are to be fetched )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order by the last digit you can use `mod(value, 10)`. If you really want to have those ending with `2` first (which I suppose isn't that much stranger than the rest of the requirement) then you can use a `case` statement within the order by clause:

```
with t42 as(
  select 3234445452 as value from dual
  union all select 3432454542 from dual
  union all select 1234567890 from dual
  union all select 3432432441 from dual
)
select value
from t42
order by case when mod(value, 10) = 2 then 0 else 1 end, mod(value, 10), value;

     VALUE
----------
3234445452 
3432454542 
1234567890 
3432432441
```

So that puts those ending with `2` first, then the remainder ordered by the last digit, so the end 'buckets' would be `2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, ...`, from the first two arguments of the `order by`. Then the third argument orders the values numerically within each 'bucket', which puts `3234445452` before `3432454542`.

---

You can put other fields in the `order by`, sure. You just need to have a `case` for the string too; this might be overkill:

```
with t42 as(
  select 3234445452 as num, 'John' as createdby from dual
  union all select 3432454542, 'John' from dual
  union all select 3432454542, 'Alex' from dual
  union all select 1234567890, 'John' from dual
  union all select 3432432441, 'John' from dual
)
select num, createdby
from t42
order by case when mod(num, 10) = 2 then 0 else 1 end,
  case when createdby = 'John' then 0 else 1 end,
  mod(num, 10), num, createdby;

       NUM CREATEDBY
---------- ---------
3234445452 John      
3432454542 John      
3432454542 Alex      
1234567890 John      
3432432441 John
```

Comment: Can we have another column(varchar2) which needs to be used along with the above.Pls see modified details..

Comment: @Nagarjuna - of course you can. Answer updated to show what I think you want now.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT field,
       SUBSTR (field,LENGTH (TRIM (field)), 1),

FROM table

Sample

Value                 last  Field, Lenght,  field without length spaces
00004                   4        20                   5